# Определение алгоритма хэширования

Tags: криптография, хеширование, криптоаналитика

Добрый день!

Прошу помочь определить алгоритм хэширования по следующим данным:
[Ссылка на pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/PnzM17J1)

где полученный хэш указан после gameKey=...
Если надо, могу выслать еще данных.

Answer (score 2):

1. По вашим данным длина хэша составляет 128 бит (16 байт)
2. Этому критерию удовлетворяет довольно много хэш-функций (считая, что иногда практикуется обрезание хэша)
3. Но что-то подсказывает мне что это обычный [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) - считается не очень сильным алгоритмом со слабыми местами.

P.S. Не х**е**ш, а х**э**ш

Comment: > Не хеш, а хэш

Я бы на вашем месте не был столь категоричен.

Нормы русского языка о передаче звука [э], закрепленные в Большом толковом словаре русского языка, а так же, в толковом словаре В. Даля и справочнике Розенталя, гласят, что в иностранных словах для передачи звука [э] после согласных, должна использоваться буква "е" (компьютер, тест, хеш). Кроме того, именно такое написание закреплено в орфографическом словаре РАН.

Comment: @falstaf с учетом того, что сайт называется хЭшкод я бы не был столь категоричен - сЭр!

Comment: @falstaf вы проспали другой момент: языковая норма это то как люди говорят и пишут, а не то что написано в правилах. Язык он живой и постоянно меняется. Правила пишут постфактум - после того как языковая норма устанавливается. Ничего страшного, лингвисты потом перепишут правила и добавят в словарь что-то типа: *за исключением слов сэр, хэш, пэр, мэр и проч.*

Comment: > языковая норма это то как люди говорят и пишут, а не то что написано в правилах

Принимая во внимание безграмотность преобладающей части населения, выходит, что языковая норма — это "карова" и "моё кофе". Так ведь *получаеться*, следуя вашей же логике?

Comment: @falstaf я ожидал это возражение :). Вряд ли конечно когда то будет *карова* или *моё кофе*, хотя все может статься. Сейчас это признак образованности, а лет 100 назад признаком образованности было умение правильной расстановки буквы *ять*. Речь немного о другом: приведенные вами примеры уже устоялись за сотни лет, а слово *хэш* относительно новое и речь идет о языковой норме этого нового заимствования. Кроме того, почитайте [российский ГОСТ по хэшированию](http://protect.gost.ru/document.aspx?control=7&id=180209) - официальный документ между прочим и везде *хэш*

Comment: То есть Большой толковый словарь русского языка, словарь В. Даля, справочник Розенталя, а так же орфографический словарь РАН для вас не являются авторитетным источником знаний о языковых нормах и, в том числе, правилах заимствований? А технический ГОСТ — так то да, несомненный аргумент.

-----

Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что при составлении нормативно-технических документов вопросы правописания и соответствия литературным нормам являются второстепенными? А стало быть, и использовать эти документы для определения правильного написания слова — плохая затея.

Comment: Это точно. Тем более, что правильное написание слова *хэш* определяют не лингвисты, а криптографы - среди которых нет ни одного который пишет *хеш*

Comment: "хеш" — [1 630 000 результатов][1], "хэш" — [710 000 результатов][2].

-----

"хеширование" — [295 000 результатов][3], "хэширование" — [29 700 результатов][4].

  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q="хеш"
  [2]: https://www.google.ru/search?q="хэш"
  [3]: https://www.google.ru/search?q="хеширование"
  [4]: https://www.google.ru/search?q="хэширование"

Comment: Ну конечно. Вы же сами говорили о поголовной безграмотности населения. Криптографов увы меньше чем остальных гномеков :) Отошлю вас на сайт известного российского криптографа [Сергея Панасенко](http://panasenko.ru/) (лично знаком с ним) автора нескольких солидных монографий по криптографии и члена многочисленных экспертных советов по оной же - он никогда не пишет *хеш* - понимаю не авторитет :)

Comment: @falstaf, в определенной среде всегда существует определенный жаргон, и никакие официально признанные авторитеты носителям этого жаргона не указ. 

Вот так, если по простому.